# Authorize and authenticate canvas app users with php-sdk and oauth

Tags: canvas, authorization, facebook-php-sdk, oauth-2.0

Egads...programming for Facebook these days is like going on a scavenger hunt. The info on FB is incomplete, their own code examples often don't work and you just want to go home and have a beer.

Before I completely lose my hair, can someone please point me to a working php-sdk code example that checks if a user a) is logged in b) has authorized the app (with extended permissions) and c) gives me an array with the permission they've authorized?

I did an app about a year or so ago and wow, it seems things have changed. I've Googled and Googled, but it seems like all the code I've found is old, incomplete or just plain wrong.

I've downloaded the latest php-sdk Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the tutorials on this site

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/

Comment: I grabbed the sample code and went to my apps URL. Didn't get an authorization message, just the "An error occurred. Please try again later" message that I've seen people mention.

Comment: Looked at the code at http://wordpress.3dn.nl/2011/06/01/facebook-associates/  Getting a "Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" error.

Comment: I actually ended going back to thinkdiff and I think I must have originally missed something as the code was now working. Thanks again for the link.